# Tell scrapy to start executing some requests and not wait on creating all of them

Tags: python, asynchronous, scrapy, scheduler

I have a scrapy spider which downloads an input file from my private Github with around 1 million playlist IDs, which I want to search for using Chartmetric (a music data analytics tool). To this end, I download the file

```
def start_requests(self):
        self.logger.info("starting requests")
        
        yield scrapy.Request('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XXXX/XXXX/main/unique_playlist_ids.csv.gz',
                             method = 'GET',
                             callback = self.do_requests,
                             headers = {'Authorization': 'token XXX'})
```

In my do_requests function, I do the following (looping over all the rows in the unzipped dataset) and creating requests.

```
def do_requests(self,response):
        data = BytesIO(response.body)
        with gzip.open(data, 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            playlists = [row[0] for row in reader]
        
        for n,playlist_id in enumerate(playlists):
            search_data = {"q": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/"+playlist_id, "type": "playlists", "limit": "1"}
            
            yield scrapy.Request(url = "https://api.chartmetric.com/api/search?" + urlencode(search_data), 
                                 method='GET',
                                 callback=self.parse_playlist,
                                 meta = {"spotify_playlist_id": playlist_id},
                                 priority = -n,
                                 dont_filter=True)
```

That's it! However, scrapy loops over all 1 million rows and starts to create requests but not actually executing (and then parsing them with self.parse_playlist) but instead only starts after all 1 million rows have been looped over. Interestingly, this does not happen if I use a local CSV file instead of downloading an input file. It should also be said that I have a custom middleware which creates and rotates 3 tokens when the spider starts in order to use the Chartmetric API, but this should not really matter. How do I tell scrapy to start actually executing the requests instead of waiting until 1 million are scheduled?

I tried using
`priority = -n`
or
`priority = n`
in the loop, but to no avail.